# Docker pull in pipeline from azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In azure devops among all the Docker task, its not include the "pull" ( I dont know why ). How would be the correct way to do a docker pull to my repository.
I m using the following code the image its being pull but I dot know where the image is pulled.

```
- bash: |
     echo "pulling image: "$(imageName)
     docker pull $(imageName)
  displayName: "Docker pull"
```

There its not another way to do that inside a docker task ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check by running another command to list down the `docker images` after the pull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always log `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`
and you can also specify the build source like this:

```
 - script:  docker pull $(imageName)
   workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/front-end/myAppFront/
   displayName: 'Docker Pull'
```